# Unable to capture and save image using AVCapturePhotoOutput in macOS app

Tags: ios, swift, macos, camera, avfoundation

I'm developing a macOS app that captures an image using the front camera when a button is clicked. The green light of the camera turns on when the button is clicked, but no image is saved. I also see some error messages in the console:

```bash
2023-08-13 13:02:54.978411+0200 button_to_image[23599:3209684] Metal API Validation Enabled
2023-08-13 13:02:55.155150+0200 button_to_image[23599:3209684] [] CMIO_DAL_PlugInManagement.cpp:880:CreatePlugIn Could not find plugin with kCMIOHardwarePlugInTypeID
2023-08-13 13:02:55.175844+0200 button_to_image[23599:3209684] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000039a00a0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
objc[23599]: class `NSKVONotifying_AVCapturePhotoOutput' not linked into application
```

I've checked the camera box in App Sandbox and Hardened Runtime, added AVFoundation.framework to my frameworks, and added 'NSCameraUsageDescription' to my Custom macOS Target Properties. I've tried running the app in the macOS simulator and also exported the app as 'copy app' to run it locally. None of these steps have resolved the issue.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AppKit
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var capturedImage: NSImage? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Click the button!")
            Button(action: {
                captureImage()
            }) {
                Text("Capture Image")
            }
            if let img = capturedImage {
                Image(nsImage: img)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func captureImage() {
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        captureSession.startRunning()
        
        let output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(output)
        
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: PhotoCaptureDelegate { image in
            self.capturedImage = image
        })
    }
}

class PhotoCaptureDelegate: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    let completionHandler: (NSImage?) -> Void

    init(completionHandler: @escaping (NSImage?) -> Void) {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else { return }
        let image = NSImage(data: imageData)
        completionHandler(image)

        // Save the image to a file
        let desktopURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = desktopURL.appendingPathComponent("capturedImage.jpg")
        try? imageData.write(to: fileURL)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I capture and save an image using AVCapturePhotoOutput in my macOS app?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Regarding your code, it seems unusual that you call captureSession.startRunning before calling captureSession.addOutput.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/setting_up_a_capture_session) for setting up a capture session does it the other way around.  The documentation also says it is important to call beginConfiguration and commitConfiguration around changes to the inputs and outputs.  Alas, even when I follow this advice I get the error.

Comment: Another data point:  When I use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput instead of AVCapturePhotoOutput, my code runs without error.

Comment: "...my code runs without error" clarification:  The supplied delegate method is called as expected, and it has a valid/ready sample buffer attached whose formatDescription has the expected image width and height and media type.  However, when I try to access this sample buffer as an image buffer (which would allow me to use this method as a workaround for the broken AVCapturePhotoOutput), it returns nil.  The sample buffer is a block buffer, not an image buffer.